# Why github shows the same commit twice?

Tags: git, github

When I check the commit log in github, I can see that a single commit becomes two different commits with different commit Ids. If the title of the first commit is XXXX, then, the second commit is Merge "XXX".

For example here:

https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible/commit/5191cdba6da69bceea29c9c0231f2b17dffda620

https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible/commit/e41b0c40501ea8906fcbdcc7d37ff6ef0cd5cf02

Those two commits are added to the branch in different days and have different ids, even though they are obviously the same patch. Why does this happen? If I want to refer to one of them, which one should I point to?

Comment: One of them is the actual change, the second one is the merge of the change.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the same commit twice.  Those are two different commits.

The identity of a commit *is* its hash ID.  The two hash IDs you have listed are:

- `5191cdba6da69bceea29c9c0231f2b17dffda620`.

  This commit has one parent commit, `389975b56cf4e5db190c1ed67fe7dab0363cb62f`.
- `e41b0c40501ea8906fcbdcc7d37ff6ef0cd5cf02`.

  This commit has two parent commits.  The first one is `8aa78399c3f9650ae9ac7db0f0fc520e11f3be6a`, and the second is `5191cdba6da69bceea29c9c0231f2b17dffda620`—i.e., the second parent of the second commit you asked about is the first commit you asked about.

That is, as [choroba commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039169/why-github-shows-the-same-commit-twice#comment94913652_54039169), the first of them is the commit that made some change, and the second is the merge commit that the authors of the repository used to *combine* the first commit into their collection of commits.

Every commit in Git has one of these hash IDs, and every commit's hash ID is unique.<sup>1</sup>  That's why these things are so long and so ugly: Git needs to *guarantee* that these hash IDs are not only unique now, compared to every commit ever made over the last ten years (see footnote 1), but also for every commit ever *to* be made over the next *ten thousand* years (again, see footnote 1).  Note that the hash ID is computed by doing a cryptographic checksum over the *data contained within the commit*, so that it not only uniquely identifies the commit, it also acts as a check to make sure that no one has poisoned the content: changing even a single bit of data *within* the commit results in a totally new-and-different hash ID.

Because the hash IDs are big and ugly, people don't normally use them directly.  We use things like branch names—which record *one* hash ID, but that hash ID evolves so that it always means *the latest commit on the branch*—or tag names.  Tag names record one hash ID, and—at least by intent—never change which hash ID they record (i.e., they change only if the person managing the tag is malicious or capricious).

Given a commit that contains the hash IDs of its parent commit or commits, Git can find the parents.  Those parents also contain the hash IDs of *their* parents, so Git can find the grandparents.  Those grandparents contain hash IDs, so Git can find more ancestors.  This means that given a single commit hash ID, Git can find the *entire ancestry of that commit*, back to the beginning of time (well, of time-for-that-commit-chain).  Hence, if you give Git a list of the commit hash IDs of *every branch and tag in a repository*, Git can find *all* the commits in that repository, by traversing these parent chains.  And that's the entire contents of the repository, except for ancillary data like branch reflogs (which are private to one repository, not transferred across clones).

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, this uniqueness requirement is true only within repositories that will be commingled.  That is, some particular hash ID can be re-used for two different commits, but *only if you never want to put both those commits together into a single repository.*  Predicting which commits will ever go into which repository is too difficult: it's far simpler just to throw more bits into the hash ID.

The SHA-1 hashes that Git currently employs use 160 bits, and this is slowly proving to be insufficient,<sup>2</sup> so the Git folks have a migration plan that will increase this to 256 bits.  This will mess, a little bit, with the concept of "one unique hash ID per commit": instead, there will be one unique hash ID, using either the old style or the new style.  If it's the new style, the commit will have a second, old-style hash ID that's around for compatibility but is only used to identify the commit in the case of an emergency where the new-style one is missing, i.e., when talking to a Git that doesn't understand the new-style IDs.

<sup>2</sup>The insufficiency is not because there aren't enough bits to uniquely number every atom in the universe, but rather because, by throwing enough compute power at the problem, bad actors can generate deliberate hash collisions.